# Add older Python version to Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

My *Visual Studio 2022* is equipped with *Python 3.9 x64*. I would like to add *Python 3.8*, but Visual Studio Installer only has 3.9 version x64 or x32 as options. Can I add an older Python version to Visual Studio? Maybe install an interpreter separately and then bind it to VS somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a virtual environment to use with your project for example using

```
conda create -n env-01 python=3.9 scipy=0.15.0 astroid babel
```

Here you can find the documentation of using virtual environments in visual studio:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: Will I be able to add python 3.8 or older in such a way?

Answer (score -1):

You can install the preferable python version on your system and follow the steps below:-

1. Launch your python project in vscode
2. Click on the python interpreter on lower left corner
   [Python Interpreter Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgl8O.png)
3. Select the python version/path you'd like to use
   [Python Interpreter options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDrgr.png)
4. Done

Comment: It is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio _Code_, they are not the same

Comment: oh, sorry. My bad.